# React native - Redux - Can't access state variable

Tags: react-native, redux

## The Situation

I am trying to implement redux state management in my react native application.
The following example is quite simple. When the user has logged in,  the application will save the authorization token to keychain/keystore and also to redux store.

Following the tutorials, I created the following `action`:

```
export const SET_TOKEN = 'SET_TOKEN'

export const setToken = (token) => {
  return {
    type: SET_TOKEN,
    payload: token
  }
}
```

I also created the reducer:

```
export const tokenReducer = async (state={token: ''}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_TOKEN:
      return {
        ...state,
        token: action.payload
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  groups: groupsReducer,
  token: tokenReducer
});

export default rootReducer
```

Then I connect the Login component to the redux store:

```
class Login extends Component {...}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    token: state.token
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    setToken: (token) => dispatch(setToken(token))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login)
```

I use `react navigation`, so in the `App.js` I have the following code.

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import rootReducer from "./src/store/reducers/reducers";

const store = createStore(rootReducer);
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(SwitchStack)

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer/>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

This is all according to `react navigation` and `redux` documentation.

## The problem

When I print the `this.props` in `componentDidMount`, I can see the token key in the props object. The problem is that this `token` object doesnt have the string value. Instead I can see the `Promise` of the `tokenReducer`. Anything I have tried until now, returns `undefined` or errros. When i fire the `login` function, the action saves the token in the store and then I see actual value in the props, which is in form of `Promise {_55: {token: 'tokenValue'}}`

## The Question

How can I get the actual token from the store?

Comment: try to remove async modifier from your tokenReducer function. No need for async in reducers, it modifies your function so that it returns a promise instead of a new state value

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I literally spent most of my work yesterday trying to fix this issue :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `async` declaration of your `tokenReducer` function.

The async function implicitly returns Promise as a result, and that promise object is passed as prop to the react component (as you have observed).
Reducers should only return a new state value and should not contain async code.

To resolve your issue just remove `async` modifier from your reducer function.

```
export const tokenReducer = (state={token: ''}, action) => {...}
```